# Socket.IO server throttling a fast client

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a server that uses socket.io and I need a way of throttling a client that is sending the server data too quickly.  The server exposes both a TCP interface and a socket.io interface - with the TCP server (from the `net` module) I can use `socket.pause()` and `socket.resume()`, and this effectively throttles the client.  But with socket.io's `socket` class there are no `pause()` and `resume()` methods.

What would be the easiest way of getting feedback to a client that it is overwhelming the server and needs to slow down?  I liked `socket.pause()` and `socket.resume()` because it didn't require any additional code on the client-side - backup the TCP socket and things naturally slow down.  Any equivalent for socket.io?

Update: I provide an API to interact with the server (there is currently a python version which runs over TCP and a JavaScript version which uses socket.io).  So I don't have any real control over what the client does.  Which is why using `socket.pause()` and `socket.resume()` is so great - backing up the TCP stream slows the python client down no matter what it tries to do.  I'm looking for an equivalent for a JavaScript client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With enough digging I found this:

```
this.manager.transports[this.id].socket.pause();
```

and

```
this.manager.transports[this.id].socket.resume();
```

Granted this probably won't work if the socket.io connection isn't a web sockets connection, and may break in a future update, but for now I'm going to go with it.  When I get some time in the future I'll probably change it to the `QUOTA_EXCEEDED` solution that Pascal proposed.

Comment: How would you use this? For example after a client is connected and you have their socket, where do you put this code?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a dirty way to achieve throttling. Although this is a old post; some people may benefit from it:

First register a middleware:

```
io.on("connection", function (socket) {

 socket.use(function (packet, next) {
    if (throttler.canBeServed(socket, packet)) {
        next();
    }
 });
 //You other code ..
});
```

canBeServed is a simple throttler as seen below:

```
function canBeServed(socket, packet) {
 if (socket.markedForDisconnect) {
     return false;
 }

 var previous = socket.lastAccess;
 var now = Date.now();
 if (previous) {
    var diff = now - previous;

    //Check diff and disconnect if needed.
    if (diff < 50) {
        socket.markedForDisconnect = true;
        setTimeout(function () {
            socket.disconnect(true);
        }, 1000);
        return false;
    }
}

socket.lastAccess = now;

return true;
}
```

You can use process.hrtime() instead of Date.time().

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you should slow down your clients.  If one client can send too fast for your server to keep up, this is not going to go very well with 100s of clients.

One way to do this would be have the client wait for the reply for each emit before emitting anything else.  This way the server can control how fast the client can send by only answering when ready for example, or only answer after a set time.

If this is not enough, when a client exceeded x requests per second, start replying with something like QUOTA_EXCEEDED error, and ignore the data they send in.  This will force external developers to make their app behave as you want them to do.

Comment: Unfortunately I merely provide an API to interact with the server; I don't have any direct control over how the client works.  Which is why `socket.pause()` is so perfect - the client can't get around the blocking of the TCP stream.

Comment: Well, then, if a client starts sending in too many requests, start sending an error back like QUOTA_EXCEEDED.  This is what a lot of APIs do.  This should get the client's attention, and its developer too.  Try to make it clear whether the client exceeded per minute quota, or per day quota.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a callback on your server somewhere which normally sends back the response to your client, you could try and change it like this:

before:

```
  var respond = function (res, callback) {
    res.send(data);
  };
```

after

```
var respond = function (res, callback) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        res.send(data);
      }, 500); // or whatever delay you want.
  };
```

Comment: There is a response for all messages but the client does not have to wait for the response before sending more data.  The client is not written by me so I can't control how it works.

Comment: I see. it's the incoming requests you want to throttle. I think you'll  need to look at the socket.io code and see if you can get access to the socket (which is going to be there somewhere). Nice little challenge! (I agree doing it server side is best)

Answer (score 0):

As another suggestion, I would propose a solution like this:
It is common for MySQL to get a large amount of requests which would take longer time to apply than the rate the requests coming in.
The server can record the requests in a table in db assuming this action is fast enough for the rate the requests are coming in and then process the queue at a normal rate for the server to sustain. This buffer system will allow the server to run slow but still process all the requests.

But if you want something sequential, then the request callback should be verified before the client can send another request. In this case, there should be a server ready flag. If the client is sending request while the flag is still red, then there can be a message telling the client to slow down.

Answer (score 0):

simply wrap your client emitter into a function like below

```
let emit_live_users = throttle(function () {
    socket.emit("event", "some_data");
}, 2000);
```

using use a throttle function like below

```
function throttle(fn, threshold) {
    threshold = threshold || 250;
    var last, deferTimer;

    return function() {
        var now = +new Date, args = arguments;
        if(last && now < last + threshold) {
            clearTimeout(deferTimer);
            deferTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                last = now;
                fn.apply(this, args);
            }, threshold);
        } else {
            last = now;
            fn.apply(this, args);
        }
    }
}
```